# Promise.all doesn't wait for new Promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, single-page-application

This is part of a spa that uses nodejs and jquery. The getToday function console logs "result:" so the whole thing should console log 1, then result:, then 2 but it does not wait for getToday to complete. The output is 1, 2, result.

```
app.get('/incidents/all', function(req, res){
    let data = globals.dataTopdesk;
    let output = {}
    Promise.all([
        data.length,
        calculateProcessingStatus(data),
        calculateOnHold(data),
        calculateOpen(data),
        calculateStatus(data),
        calculateCallType(data);
    ])
    .then(function(values) {
        output.all = values[0]
        output.processingStatus = values[1],
        output.onHold = values[2],
        output.open = values[3],
        output.status = values[4],
        output.callType = values[5]
        return output;
    })
    .then(function(output) {
        console.log('1')
        return new Promise(resolve=> {
            output.today = getToday(db, output)
            resolve(output);
        })
    })
    .then(function(output) {
        console.log('2')
        res.send(output)
    })
    .catch (function(err) {
        res.send('failed: ' + err)
    })
})
```

Why is this not waiting for the new Promise to resolve?

Comment: `getToday` is a Promise?

Comment: You mean the new promise inside the one `then()`?  Why would it?  Promise.all doesn't know anything about it.  That's not a promise you gave it

Comment: The code in `getToday()` itself is where the problem is.

Comment: `output.today = getToday(db, output)` isn't going to wait for whatever async stuff `getToday()` does.

Comment: getToday is an async function that awaits another function with a promise and returns an object. Taplar may have the answer already.

Comment: Inside of your then you are returning a promise but you don't wait for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `getToday` is async and returns itself a promise, add it inside the chain without wrapping with an extra promise which looks useless:

```js
  return getToday().then(data => {
    output.today = data;
    return output;
  });
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks so much. I will mark it as the answer in 4 minutes.